# Scope constant for email using GoogleApiClient.Builder

Tags: android, google-plus, google-oauth

The list of Google+ Authorization scopes are listed here: https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth. Fine...

In the QuickStart example for Android client, the code for obtaining a GoogleApiClient instance looks like as shown below, but with the "Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN" scope. But I want to have the "email" scope instead. I cannot find the constant for the "email" scope.

```
  private GoogleApiClient buildGoogleApiClient() {
// When we build the GoogleApiClient we specify where connected and
// connection failed callbacks should be returned, which Google APIs our
// app uses and which OAuth 2.0 scopes our app requests.
return new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
    .addApi(Plus.API, Plus.PlusOptions.builder().build())
    .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN) // I WANT AN email SCOPE!!!
    .build();
```

}

Do I have to create the *Scope* instance myself? For example:

```
Scope emailScope = new Scope("email"); // like this?????
```

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish with it?

Comment: I want to be able to access features advertised in the "email" authorization scope. (https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth)

Comment: once you are connected just call `Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName()` and you get the email address

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName()](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/Account.html#getAccountName(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient)) to retrieve the email address of the logged in user:

```
// Note mGoogleApiClient must be connected for this to work
String email = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);
```

One note as per the developer documentation:

> Gets the account name resolved by Google Play services. The permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />` must be declared in your `AndroidManifest.xml` to use this method.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer my question. So it sounds like there is really no constant for the email scope? The thing is, I want to be able to call a Google EndPoint method later on, after the user is "logged in" as illustrated here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/auth From this doc, it looks like the scope value in the @Api annotation needs to match whatever I defined in my Android client code - hence my desire to use the "email" constant scope.

Comment: Plus is now deprecated, can anyone tell me - what is the new method?

Comment: @KhaledH - try reading the [Google Sign In documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/people)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new scope for it. Here's what works for me:

```
     Builder builder = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
    .addApi(Plus.API)
    .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE)
    .addScope(new Scope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"))
```